# Как узнать разницу в днях между датами?

Tags: javascript

сейчас получаю в милисекундах

```js
let now = new Date();
let date = new Date(2021, 4, 25, 12, 59, 59);

let diff = now - date; 
console.log(diff); // разница в миллисекундах
```

Answer (score 0):

Поделить на 1000 что-бы получить секунды,
Поделить на 60 что-бы получить минуты,
Поделить на 60 что-бы получить часы,
Поделить на 24 что-бы получить сутки.
С помощью `toFixed(2)` округляем до двух мест после запятой.

```js
let now = new Date();
let date = new Date(2021, 4, 25, 12, 59, 59);

let diff = now - date;
let output = diff/1000/60/60/24;
console.log(output.toFixed(2) + " days");
```